# table sorter images not applying in tablesorter.js?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I am trying to apply the sorter images to table sorter table like the below.But the styles are not applying.
using the below js file

```
https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter
```

By default themes are applying so my table design is changing .
i don't want the table sorter themes for images i will apply customize css.
please check below code sorter images are not applying to my table sorter.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/bg.gif');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/asc.gif'); 
}
.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/desc.gif'); 
}
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#requestheader').tablesorter({
       /* theme: 'blue',*/
        sortList: [
            [1, 0]
        ],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
 </script>

 <table class="tablesorter" id="requestheader"> 
                <thead>
                   <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Please tell me how to apply sorter images to table ?let me know the how to apply css to my table?

Comment: You are getting "bg.gif" but not "asc.gif" and "desc.gif"? Or you are not getting any image?

Comment: What styles are not applying correctly? Are you getting any errors in your console? Please be more specific so we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I am not able to apply the sorter images to my table sorter table.like the above i am applying the css to table sorter.

Comment: i added tablesorter.js,tablesorter.min.js. the sorter images appearing in tablesorter.min.js but why the images are not showing while using tablesorter.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your jQuery code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#requestheader').tablesorter({
       /* theme: 'blue',*/
        sortList: [
            [1, 0]
        ],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried but no use.sorter images are not applying to my table.

Comment: if uncommenting the Theme:blue styles are applying .But i want to customize my table sorter styles.

Comment: i added tablesorter.js,tablesorter.min.js. the sorter images appearing in tablesorter.min.js but why the images are not showing while using tablesorter.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of tablesorter uses different class names from the original. Try using the following css:

```
.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/bg.gif');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortAsc {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/asc.gif'); 
}
.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDesc {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/desc.gif'); 
}
```

If you want to change the actual class name, then modify the [`cssAsc`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssasc) and [`cssDesc` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssdesc).