# tablesorter.js and tablesortermin.js issues?

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using the below tablesorter js files.

```
https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/master/js
```

In that tablesorter.js files not showing the sorter images when i am applying like the below.

```
<style type="text/css">
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/bg.gif');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/asc.gif'); 
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url('/Public/images/sorter/desc.gif'); 
}
    </style>
```

But tablesorter.min.js file showing the tablesorter images.Why the images are not showing while using with tablesorter.js file.I need to sort the child rows table with parent table so that using tablesorter.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#parenttheader').tablesorter({
       /* theme: 'blue',*/
        sortList: [
            [1, 0]
        ],
      widgets:['zebra', 'columns']
    });

 </script>
```

Please let me know how to apply sorter images to my table ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [table sorter images not applying in tablesorter.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075760/table-sorter-images-not-applying-in-tablesorter-js)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083835/default-themes-are-applying-in-tablesorter-while-using-tablesorter-js-file