# Default themes are applying in tablesorter while using tablesorter.js file

Tags: tablesorter

I have been facing this problem since morning, so any help would be appreciated.
I am using a 'tablesorter.js' file in which blue and green themes have been set by default.
I want to customize the themes but unable to do so. Can someone please tell me how to customize my theme for table sorter in 'tablesorter.js' file? I downloaded the js file in the below path.

```
https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/2.15.13/

$(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#requestheader').tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            sortList: [
                [1, 0]
            ],
            /* widgets:['zebra', 'columns']*/
        });
    });
```

Please tell me how to apply customized themes for table sorter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [table sorter images not applying in tablesorter.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075760/table-sorter-images-not-applying-in-tablesorter-js)

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081528/tablesorter-js-and-tablesortermin-js-issues